# How to write click event that hides a container in ReactJS?

Tags: jquery, reactjs

".b2" is classname of a button. "#subscribe" is the id of a div blank container.
the jquery hides the div container on clicking the button. how to convert this into reactjs ?

```
$(".b2").click(function(){
      $("#subscribe").hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ReactJS you will need three things:

1) A stateful component with a boolean in the state, initialized to true. This boolean will be used to show/hide the container.

2) A function to update the state of the boolean to false.

3) A render method to render the container based on the state of the boolean and the button to trigger the function.

All together you will need something like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
       showContainer: true
    }
  }

  hideContainer() {
    this.setState({ showContainer: false });
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <div>
          {this.state.showContainer && <div>MyContainer</div>}
          <button onClick={() => this.hideContainer()}>Hide container</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sdm8526c/)

Answer (score 1):

ReactJS is state and component based and you can use state to control UI in your view.

For a good introduction to how state works check out the [ReactJS docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) (specifically the State and Lifecycle section)

But you can achieve something above with the following: (untested code)

```
state = { visible: false }

<Button onClick={this.setState=({visible: !this.state.visible})}>Toggle me!</Button>

<Component visible={this.state.visible} />
```

The above will toggle the visibility of said component. Note the `visibility` prop being passed in to `<Component>`. You can access this inside the component with `props`.

More on [props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) in their docs.

Answer (score 0):

Use state to set the style of the element like this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      show: false
    };
  }

  render() {

    const { show } = this.state

    return (
      <div>
        <p style={{ display: show ? "" : "none"}}>
          Start editing to see some magic happen :)
        </p>

        <button onClick={() => this.setState({show: !show})}>
          {show ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}
        </button>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Live example here https://stackblitz.com/fork/react